# Android ParseQuery getting error: "unreachable statement"

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am attempting to query parse for every entry in a Parse Class, I am getting an error of unreachable statement yet I coded it exactly as in the Parse documents, this query is occurring from a fragment:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Inventory");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> stockList, ParseException e) {
            if(e == null){
                Log.d("stock", "Retrieved " + stockList.size());

            } else {

                Log.d("stock", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

I am using android studio

Answer (score 0):

Never mind got it turns out the line wasn't going to be executed because I placed it after the return.inflater line, incase anyone runs across the same issue